Gridstack does not adhere to dynamic drag handles
I'm currently using Gridstack in an Ember project and want to have a custom drag handle. I know this can be implemented by setting the draggable: { handle: '.my-custom-drag-handle' } in the options. But, it appears as if the drag handle is rendered after the rest of the component in Ember and so Gridstack defaults to the entire grid-stack-item class.
I tried replicating it in native JS and was able to using setTimeout. Is there any way to reconfigure gridstack to use the newly added handles? See demo here: https://jsfiddle.net/vishaalagartha/gvt4390e/9/

is there anyway you can use a modifier to setup gridstack, so that you have more control over when the gridstack thing is rendered?

I'm having exactly the same issue (using react)
